Attribute auto-calculation upon retrieval
I am trying to make a point object in 3D in python, and I have the following code
import numpy as np

class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):

        self.vector = np.matrix([x, y, z])
        self.vector.reshape(3, 1)

    def x(self): return self.vector.item((0, 0))
    def y(self): return self.vector.item((0, 1))
    def z(self): return self.vector.item((0, 2))

I am using numpy to create vertical matrices to eventually use this for a rendering engine. I want to be able to reference the x,y and z of this vector without having to type self.vector.item((0, 0)) for example. I want to be able to do point.x and get the x value from the vector automatically. I also want to be able to set the values as such: point.x = 5. Is there any way this possible?
I tried setting them at the start in the init function but then I would have to update it every time. I then made functions to there would only have to be an extra 2 chars, but setting is still not implemented.

You need to set self.vector = self.vector.reshape(3, 1) otherwise the operation is not saved to the object.

What you are wanting to do is property getter and setters.  The @property decorator returns a value without having to call the method.  I.e. use p.x instead of p.x().
To assign a value to the property, you use the @<propertyname>.setter decorator which implements assigning to the property via p.x = 3.
I added a __repr__ so the object looks nice if you are in interactive mode in Python.
import numpy as np

class Point3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.vector = np.matrix([x, y, z]).reshape(3,1)

    def __repr__(self):
        n = self.__class__.__name__
        return f'{n}({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.z})'

    @property
    def x(self): 
        return self.vector[0,0]

    @property
    def y(self): 
        return self.vector[1,0]

    @property
    def z(self): 
        return self.vector[2,0]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x_val): 
        self.vector[0,0] = x_val

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y_val): 
        self.vector[1,0] = y_val

    @z.setter
    def z(self, z_val): 
        self.vector[2,0] = z_val


Thank you so much!. Later in my code, I have the line
self.camera_pos.x += (self.player_VX / (self.fps.get_fps() + 0.1)),
this is just supposed to move the camera(self.camera is a Point3D), but the value is not being set and nothing is happening, how can I fix this?

That is an entirely new question.  Post it on SO.
